# Execute sql queries from shell script

Tags: sql, bash, postgresql, psql

I need to execute the following sql queries from bash/expect script
what is the preferred approach to run these queries from bash script

```
# psql ambari -U ambari
Password for user ambari:
psql (9.2.24)
Type "help" for help.

ambari=>
ambari=>
ambari=>
ambari=> select
ambari-> sum(case when ulo = 1  then 1 else 0 end) as ulo_1,
ambari-> sum(case when ulo = 2  then 1 else 0 end) as ulo_2,

.
.
.
```

for access PostgreSQL we do

```
psql ambari -U ambari
Password for user ambari:bigdata
```

and when we run this ( /tmp/file include the bach of the query )

```
 psql -U ambari -f /tmp/file  ambari
```

we get

```
psql: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "[local]", user "ambari", database "ambari", SSL off
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using this

```
dbhost=localhost
dbport=5432
dbuser=user
dbpass=pass
dbname=test
export PGPASSWORD="$dbpass"
dbopts="-h $dbhost -p $dbport -U $dbuser -d $dbname"
```

Then run sql script from file

```
psql $dbopts < "$path_to_sql_script"
```

Or from query var

```
query="
SELECT 1;
...
"
psql $dbopts <<< "$query"
```

Also pgpass can be set in special file `~/.pgpass` like this

```
echo "$dbhost:$dbport:$dbname:$dbname:$dbpass" > ~/.pgpass
chmod 600 ~/.pgpass
```

Comment: how to know the - dbport?

Comment: Use default 5432.

Comment: also where I can found the - dbname?

Answer (score 2):

Use switches `-c command` or `-f filename`, ie.:

```
$ psql -U ambari -c "SELECT ... ;" ambari    # > result.file
```

or:

```
$ cat file.sql
SELECT
... ;
$ psql -U ambari -f file.sql ambari          # > result.file
```

Probably `-f` as your query seems lengthy. Use `> result.file` to store the query result to a file.

As for the password, store following kind of entry to `.pgpass` file in user's home dir:

```
$ cat >> ~/.pgpass
#hostname:port:database:username:password
localhost:5432:ambari:ambari:t00M4NY53CR3t5
```

and set its rights to user's eyes only:

```
$ chmod 600 ~/.pgpass
```

Also, consider `psql -h hostname` if the database is not running in localhost (this needs to reflect in `.pgpass` entry as well).

Comment: see please the update , we run as you suggest but I think we need also to consider the password

Comment: Updated with password handling.